# Calculate incoming bytes per second in Azure Event hub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

How do I calculate the incoming bytes per **second** for an event hub namespace?
I do not control the data producer and so cannot predict the incoming bytes upfront.
I am interested in adjusting the maximum throughput units I need, without using the auto-inflate feature.
[1 TU provides 1 MB/s ingress & 2 MB/s egress](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/event-hubs/), but the metrics are reported per **minute**, not per second.

Can I make a decision based on the sum/avg/max incoming bytes reported in the Azure portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll need to use Stream Analytics to query your stream and based on the query output change your TU on Event Hub.

You can also try to use Azure Monitor, but I believe it won't group per second as you need, so you'd better try the first option.

Comment: Thanks, I created a stream analytics job to sum the size of the incoming json events in a tumbling window of 1 second. I defined a custom Javascript UDF to stringify the event and then get the UTF-8 byte count of the resulting string.

Answer (score 1):

Per second metrics cannot be reliable due to very nature of potential intermittent spikes at the traffic in and out. 1 minute averages are good to monitor and you can easily take action via a Logic App.

Check messaging metrics to monitor here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-metrics-azure-monitor#message-metrics